# PostgreSQL: How to use a lookup table to select data across multiple tables?

Tags: postgresql, psql

I have a schema with many large tables which all have the same structure. Each table has an index on its id. I also have a separate table with all the id's across the other tables, pointing to their tablename; for example, the tables in the schema:

```
Table 'A'
id     content
1      ...
2      ...
3      ...

Table 'B'
id     content
4      ...
5      ...
6      ...

Table 'C'
id     content
5      ...
6      ...
7      ...
```

(As you can see the id's are not always unique across the tables) And then a table with lookup:

```
Table 'lookup'
id     tablename
1      'A'
2      'A'
3      'A'
4      'B'
5      'B'
5      'C'
6      'B'
6      'C'
7      'C'
```

Now, how can I make a view like this?

```
SELECT 
    id, content
FROM 
    view
WHERE 
    id = 6
```

where it would select the content from B and C (where id is 6). Also, it should only do an index scan on B and C to reduce search time. Once again, there are many tables and they are very large. By far the most of the id's are unique across the tables.

How can I do this? (Or maybe, should I do it this way?)

**PS** The content of the tables is not stored into a single table because the volume is constantly growing and inserting/copying into this indexed table becomes very slow after a while. Also, it is more easy to remove specific data by just truncating separate tables.

Comment: it would be much more easy if you build your table structure using inheritance or  partitioning.

Comment: `(SELECT * FROM 'A' WHERE id <= 3) UNION ALL (SELECT * FROM 'B' WHERE id >= 4 AND id <= 6) UNION ALL (SELECT * FROM 'C' WHERE id >= 5)` might work. But as Bernando said, this sounds like a perfect use case for partitioning - except that you have some rows in multiple tables at once! Why?

Comment: @Bergi just to give some context: each table refers to a geographic region and the rows refer to geometric objects inside those regions. It can be the case that an object is present in multiple regions (on the borders). It would have its object id appear in multiple tables, but the geometries are different. I would like to create an efficient view to select all rows of an arbitrary object id across all of those tables (hundreds of them, with multiple GB per table)

Comment: @BernardoJerez I am not familiar with inheritance and partitioning, so will look into that. Many thanks.

Comment: @pklaassen And the two objects would have the same contents in both tables? That sounds like a normalisation issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for [table partitioning](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-partitioning.html):

```
CREATE TABLE object (
    country text,
    id bigint,
    content bytea,
    PRIMARY KEY (country, id)
) PARTITION BY LIST (country);


CREATE TABLE object_a PARTITION OF object FOR VALUES IN ('A');
CREATE TABLE object_b PARTITION OF object FOR VALUES IN ('B');
CREATE TABLE object_c PARTITION OF object FOR VALUES IN ('C');
```

This alone won't give you quick access by id, but simplifies managing the union and querying by country name. You'd still need the lookup table for the countries:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW lookup AS SELECT country, id FROM object;
```

Then you can do

```
SELECT content
FROM object
JOIN lookup ON object.country = lookup.country AND object.id = lookup.id
WHERE lookup.id = 6
```

Comment: Yes, I think this is what I need, at least for solving part of the problem. To answer your previous question: no, two objects would never have the same contents in both tables. Let's say that an object with id 6 is on the border of two countries A and B. It would then have a row in table A with id 6 and the one **part** of the geometry of object 6 which is located in A as its content; it would also have a row in table B with id 6 and the **other part** of the geometry of object 6 which is located in B. That might sound vague, but explaining the whole context would just take too many words.